# How to print in a file using awk command inside a ksh file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

How do I print in a .log file using awk command inside a ksh file?
The script goes this way:

```
##create file here
## Start  process 
awk 'BEGIN {
        some code here
    }
    {

##Logic here
##Print to file 

    }
    END {}
' $OUTPUTNEEDEDTOBEPRINTED
```

Comment: Just redirect your `print`s: `print ... > "my.log"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect within the `awk` code:

```
##create file here
## Start  process 
awk 'BEGIN {
        some code here
    }
    {
    print > "myfile"


    }
    END {}
' "$OUTPUTNEEDEDTOBEPRINTED"
```

Or just redirect the output of you `awk`

```
##create file here
## Start  process 
awk 'BEGIN {
        some code here
    }
    {

##Logic here
##Print to file 

    }
    END {}
' "$OUTPUTNEEDEDTOBEPRINTED" > "myfile"
```